# How to run "vue ui" with Node.js v17.2.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to use "vue ui" in my project but resently I have update node 14 to Node.js v17.2.0 and now I can't open Vue GUI. Still Ihave a problem:

```
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1390:3)
    at exports.readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/fs.js:18:20)
    at Object.safeCall [as safe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:24:8)
    at DirectoryReader.readNextDirectory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:78:10)
    at Readable.DirectoryReader.stream._read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:57:18)
    at Readable.read (node:internal/streams/readable:496:27)
    at readdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/index.js:27:21)
    at Function.readdirSyncStat (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/index.js:34:10)
    at ReaderSync.dynamicApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:64:24)
    at ReaderSync.api (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:56:25)
Emitted 'error' event on Readable instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/ewakadziolka/Desktop/vue/emmaus/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/locales'
}
```

directory that coud be founded is my lastest projest that I used Vue GUI with node 14 yet not new one where I want to use Vue GUI.
Do you have any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to install [node v16.13.1](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and now all works very well. I have my vue GUI opened on localhost 8000.

Comment: Had the same issue with "Node Latest" and using the "Node LTS" version (v16.13.1) fixed it for me as well.